# Firefox - block authentication dialog

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to block authentication dialogs?

I tried the AdBlockPlus addon. This does not seem to prevent Authorization required. I'm using selenium for browser automatisation. When there comes a authentication popup the whole programm waits until the popup is closed. So I want that firefox handles authentication popus like if I always click on cancel.

Comment: What should happen once you have prevented the user from authenticating?

Comment: Please give us more details.

Comment: It shall happen like if I click on cancel in the authenticating dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution for the problem. I’m using a modified version of the Firefox add-on AutoAuth. Normally this clicks the OK button when you visited a HTTP Authentication dialog before and saved username and password. I modified the plugin so that it always cancels the dialog.
It’s working very well on Firefox 35.

My Java Code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// create profile

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//add a extension to firefox

File extension = new File("autoauth-2.1-fx+fn.xpi");

try {

profile.addExtension(extension);

} catch (IOException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

driver.get("http://demo.tanmaysarkar.com/authentication/");

driver.get("http://demo.tanmaysarkar.com/authentication/");
try {

Thread.sleep(10000);

} catch (InterruptedException ex) {

Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

}
driver.quit();
}
}
```

You have to modify the firefox addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autoauth/. In there is the file chrome/content/overlay.js
Replace the overlay.js with my version on http://pastebin.com/XRVxJdey

I hope this helps somebody